# django-simple-history3.1.1 error when cascade deletion

Tags: python, django, class, cascade, django-simple-history

For a Django project I work on, I use *django-simple-history* to get a history of each of my models. Everything works very well when I create, modify or delete an object, the library generates a `<HistoricalObject>` each time.
My problem is when I perform a cascade deletion.

For example, I have a table B that inherits a table A. When I delete an object from my table A, it also deletes all its related objects in table B.
*Django-simple-history* generates a `<HistoricalObject>` for my table A's object but for the B's it is a "corrupted" object with "formating error" because the deleted B object refers to an A object that no longer exists and this create an error.
I can't even read the `<HistoricalObject>` of B when i query it. The error is :

> MyApp.models.tableA_object.DoesNotExist: tableA_object matching query does not exist.

I haven’t found anything on the forums about it and it really blocks me, I can’t do without cascade deletion and *django-simple-history* meets all my needs except this one.

Some infos :

- Django 4.0.3
- django-simple-history 3.1.1
- MySql
- Python 3.9.7

Thank you for your help